How do I show vpython results directly in spyder?
I'm trying to use vpython in spyder to do physics simulations, when I run the code it opens a browser window in Edge to show the result.
Is there a way I can display the results directly in spyder instead? That way I won't have to switch between applications while writing code.
Quick example script that will open a browser window:
from vpython import *
point1 = sphere(pos = vector(0,0,0))

